# Is there a way to know if a specific prop was updated without using state in React?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, antd

I'm using React, Redux, and some antd components

I'm using [this modal](https://ant.design/components/modal/#components-modal-demo-info%20this) to alert users of errors, but if you look at it, its not exactly a component, its a function, so right now I'm using `componentDidUpdate` like this:

```
componentDidUpdate () {
  if (this.props.states.ErrorReducer.displayError) {
    error(() => {
      this.props.dispatch(ErrorActionCreators.acceptError())
    }, this.props.states.ErrorReducer.errorMessage )
  }
}
```

Problem is, if I make multiple changes to state at once, for example make multiple calls to the API and they alter the state at different times, this modal open multiple times.

I could use state to do something like

```
if (this.state.displayError !== this.props.displayError {
  updateState();
  error();
}
```

But I'm avoiding using React state.

Is there anyway I can check if one specific prop was changed on the Component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the lifecycle method, componentWillReceiveProps. This gets called every time props are updated. Here's a link for help [componentWillreceiveProps](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) and a code snippet:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
  if(this.props !== nextProps){
    // your code and conditions go here
  }
}
```

You can actually compare the old props (this.props) with the new or updated props (nextProps).